How To Set File Access Just For User In Domain, With Apps Script
I have some file and folder in Google Drive. I want to set access with Apps Script.
I put access setting in  sheetDatabase,  Cell 'K3'  with  Data Validation  option : 'ARRANGED' and 'UNREGULATED'. The Domain my organization is guru.smk.belajar.id  ( and I hope I can change it later ), I place it in Cell 'K4' .
To set file / folder Access, I create Apps Script, but I Can't set user acces with domain address restrictions.
It is possible to set user acces with domain ( @sampledomain.com ) address restrictions ( not just user ( user@sampledomain.com ) ?
 function updatePermissions() {

    var domainSetting = sheetDatabase.getRange('K3').getValue();
    var domain        = sheetDatabase.getRange('K4').getValue(); // As a sample, my domain was @guru.smk.belajar.id

    Logger.log("Domain "+domain)

 // Set Folder Share Access  
    var folderAplikasiPklID = sheetSetting.getRange(6, 3).getValue(); //  Folder ID
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderAplikasiPklID);

 // Set Spreadsheet Share Access
    var spreadsheetID = sheetSetting.getRange(7, 3).getValue(); // Spreadsheet ID
    var ssJurnalPKL = DriveApp.getFileById(spreadsheetID);

   if (domainSetting === 'ARRANGED') {
// Set folder to view only by domain users
  folder.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.PRIVATE, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);
  folder.addViewers(domain);

// Set file to edit only by users in the specified domain
 ssJurnalPKL.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.PRIVATE, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW); // Restrict to private first
 var viewers = ssJurnalPKL.getViewers();
 for (var i = 0; i < viewers.length; i++) {
     ssJurnalPKL.removeViewer(viewers[i]);
 }
 var editors = ssJurnalPKL.getEditors();
     for (var i = 0; i < editors.length; i++) {
     ssJurnalPKL.removeEditor(editors[i]);
 }
 ssJurnalPKL.addEditors(domain); // Give Editor Access to User in  domain

  } else if (domainSetting === 'UNREGULATED') {
// Set file to edit by anyone with the link
   ssJurnalPKL.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.EDIT);
 }

  Logger.log('Permissions updated successfully.');
  };


In order to give permission to a domain, Drive API is used. The sample script is as follows.
Sample script:
Before you test this script, please enable Drive API v3 at Advanced Google services.
const fileId = "###"; // <--- Please set your file ID.
const resource = {
  role: "writer",
  type: "domain",
  domain: "###" // <--- Please set your domain.
};
Drive.Permissions.create(resource, fileId, { supportsAllDrives: true });


If the value of role is different from your actual situation, please modify it.
If you want to include more properties, you can see them at the official document.
If the file of fileId is not included in the shared drive, you can remove supportsAllDrives: true.

Reference:

Method: permissions.create of Drive API v3


Thanks @Tanaike. Your modification script work.

@PSAB Plalangan Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.
